# looking for a best practice - C# - Read file to Object, edit and save back to - Not XML, Json

Tags: c#, object, serialization, deserialization

First of all, I only found examples on google and here .json to object or .xml to object.
But I have a pre-defined code that I want to read in, edit and save exactly or only changed things.

For the context, it's about skin mods, i.e. paths to images and changing their properties

### The File

```
Unit
{
 economy : _.abcd.1234 {
  player : _.defg.5678
  vehicles: 10
  vehicle[0] : _.hijk.9012
  vehicle[1] : 
  ... and so on
  vehicle[9] : _.lmno.3456
  assigned_vehicle: _.hijk.9012
  ...
 }
 ... other things
 vehicle : _.hijk.9012 {
  license_plate: "M XX 69"
  accessories: 41
  accessories[0]: _.af25.1780
  ...
  accessories[40]: _.6e68.a620
  data_path: "/def/vehicle/mercedes/data.txt"
 }
 ... other vehicles
 ... other accessories
 accessory : _.af25.1780 {
  offset: 4
  paint_color: (1, 1, 1)
  wear: 0
  data_path: "/def/vehicle/t_wheel/single_385_55_steel.sii"
 }
 ... other accessories
 ... more things with format
 object : name {
  property : value
  property : object
  property : count
  property[x] : value
 }
}
```

actually i only need the value of assigned_vehicle and then the part as an object, edited and then only write the part back.
Of course, it would be nicer to read everything in and save it completely again.
So basically my own serializer and deserializer for this format.

so what do you mean?
Read in file line by line and create and fill objects manually
**or** is there a better solution than creating umpteen objects and filling them by hand?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your question. What you're asking for is relevant to do a design, an architecture or a software choice based on opinion and not to solve a programming, an algorithm or a pattern issue with some code. To help you improve your requests please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: Say for instance, you need to add an extra character to some arbitrary part of the file, what do you think will need to happen to rest of the file? You are going to have to load this in to memory parse and edit it or stream it line by line parse and edit it then stream it back to another file. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @OlivierRogier the design, architecture etc. is done UWP App with MVVM :D
and now i'm looking for a nice solution to edit the text file

Comment: @00110001 that is not the problem, that would be feasible, but let's say in 2 weeks I would like to edit another part of the file and then I can go through all the lines again and edit. but how can I solve this object-oriented?

Comment: Do you know the format and specification of the file ? Is it some common known format. Maybe there is a parser already built for you, otherwise you will need to roll your own

Comment: @00110001 no unfortunately no known format, already searched it,

Comment: @00110001 yes the format is like my example. so what i need is my own "parser"?

Comment: Well, the term parser is used loosely. Find and replace might work good enough for you atm ( considering its formatted in a readable line by line format)

Answer (score 0):

Can something like that work?

I don't know what a parser / serializer / deserializer should look like.
Or not even what my class is anyway

```
public static void ParseLocalSaveGame(SaveGame saveGame)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(saveGame.Path))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains("Unit"))
            {
                // beginning of file
                // jump to the first "usable" line
                sr.ReadLine();
                sr.ReadLine();
                continue;
            }

            if (line.Contains(""))
            {
                // skip empty line
                sr.ReadLine(); 
                continue;
            }
            else if (line.Contains("economy"))
            {
                saveGame.Economy = new Economy(line.Replace("economy :", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("{", ""));
                ParseSaveGameEconomy(sr);
                continue;
            }
            else if (line.Contains("vehicle"))
            {
                Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle(line.Replace("vehicle :", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("{", ""));
                ParseSaveGameVehicle(sr, vehicle);
                saveGame.Vehicles.Add(vehicle);
                continue;
            }
            else if (line.Contains("accessory"))
            {
                Accessory accessory = new Accessory(line.Replace("accessory :", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("{", ""));
                ParseSaveGameAccessory(sr, accessory);
                saveGame.Accessories.Add(accessory);
                continue;
            }
            else if (line.Contains("}"))
            {
                //This should be the last line
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                // This should not happen!
                // TODO: Write Error
            }
        }
    }
}
```